# GStreamer and Qt 5.10

Tags: qt, gstreamer, qtgstreamer

So i'm currently using Ubuntu 18 and i'm having trouble with GStreamer and Qt 5.10

To start, all Qt example return the same error: `CameraBin error: "Device '/dev/video0' does not support progressive interlacing"`

To make sure linux does recognize drivers and so on, i tried to open my webcam thru vlc, which was successfull! so the problem really is that `interlace` option. Does anyone know how do i change it from Qt QtGstreamer of if i could change it in some outside GStreamer file? Thanks for the attention!

Comment: I don't believe VLC and GStreamer share any common code or libraries, so that test won't confirm whether or not GStreamer is compatible with your device.

Comment: Oh i see.. I tought, somehow, VLC would auto-detect that my device doesnt accept that "interlace" and change it
Do youhave any toughts of how could i proceed? I'm sincerely out of ideias. Thanks Anyhow!